# OS on flash drive acts differently on different ports of the same machine cryptsetup/busybox

Tags: boot, usb, busybox, cryptsetup

I have Ubuntu **installed** into a usb flash drive with encryption enabled. My laptop (XPS13) has 2 USB ports.

When I insert the flash drive into let's say port A, it works just fine; cryptsetup comes up, I enter my password and it goes on.

But when I insert it into port B the first thing I see is Ubuntu loading screen and after 2 minutes it takes me to BusyBox screen. It never shows cryptsetup.
By pressing `CTRL+D` in BusyBox it keeps printing:

```
/run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
```

What's going on?

BTW I also run Ubuntu from this flash drive on my windows via Virtual Box (works fine).

Comment: Is one of them a USB 2 port and the other a USB 3 port? Is there any [other] evidence that one of the USB ports is damaged (mechanically or electronically)?

Comment: @sudodus Both are USB 3. I don't think if they're damaged.

Comment: What happens if you shutdown the computer, and wait for 5 minutes, and boot again? There should be no difference, if both ports are good, and connected internally in the same way. But things like this happen. USB was not designed primarily for booting, so there can be glitches.